# Doubt in Lang's proof that normal extensions remain normal under lifting (Theorem V.3.4, *Algebra*)

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, normal-extension

> **Theorem 3.4.** *Normal extensions remain normal under lifting. If $K \supset E \supset k$ and $K$ is normal over $k$, then $K$ is normal over $E$. If $K_1$, $K_2$ are normal over $k$ and are contained in some field $L$, then $K_1 K_2$ is normal over $k$, and so is $K_1 \cap K_2$.*
>
> *Proof.* For our first assertion, let $K$ be normal over $k$, let $F$ be any extension of $k$, and assume $K$, $F$ are contained in some bigger field. Let $\sigma$ be an embedding of $KF$ over $F$ (in $F^*$). Then $\sigma$ induces the identity on $F$, hence on $k$, and by hypothesis its restriction to $K$ maps $K$ into itself. We get $(KF)^\sigma = K^\sigma F^\sigma = KF$ whence $KF$ is normal over $F$.

Lang proves the above theorem in his book *Algebra*. The only first part of the proof seems to be weird, namely that "lifting respects normal extensions".

Indeed, he has shown that any embedding $\sigma$ of $KF$ in $F^a$ over $F$ gives an automorphism. And this is one of the equivalent definitions of normal extensions.

But we also have to show that $KF$ is algebraic over $F,$ which I do not see in his proof (because the definition of normal extension requires an algebraic extension with certain properties).

How to show that $KF$ is algebraic over $F$?

Would be very grateful for any help!

Comment: Lang already proved that you can lift algebraic extensions: If $K/k$ is algebraic, and $F$ is any extension of $k$, then $KF/F$ is algebraic.

Answer (score 1):

*Pulling down the comment by @ArturoMagidin.*

---

Lang has already shown that you can lift algebraic extensions: if $K/k$ is algebraic, and $F$ is any extension of $k$, then $KF/F$ is algebraic.

For reference, see Proposition 1.7 of Chapter V (page 228, third edition):

> **Proposition 1.7.** *The class of algebraic extensions is distinguished, and so is the class of finite extensions.*